# Get the host FQDN from and send it to the Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, operating-system, hostname

I am working on an Angular application that should get the FQDN of the client host on which the browser is running.
Is there a way to get the client hostname with JavaScript, TypeScript, or Angular?